# Simple getJSON() function

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

[SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) is an extremely useful add-on for Swift, importable via various methods (CocoaPods, Carthage, etc.) and I use it within many of my projects as they commonly require JSON files.  So I wanted a nice simple function that I could call with necessary arguments and get my raw String value from my JSON file.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1. We will create one protocol with one constructor method in it and Model class

```
protocol JSONable {
    init?(parameter: JSON)
}

class Style: JSONable {
    let ID              :String!
    let name            :String!

    required init(parameter: JSON) {
        ID            = parameter["id"].stringValue
        name          = parameter["name"].stringValue
    }

    /*  JSON response format
    {
      "status": true,
      "message": "",
      "data": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Style 1"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Style 2"
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "Style 3"
        }
      ]
    }
    */
}
```

Step 2. We will create extension of JSON which will convert JSON to model class type object

```
extension JSON {
    func to<T>(type: T?) -> Any? {
        if let baseObj = type as? JSONable.Type {
            if self.type == .array {
                var arrObject: [Any] = []
                for obj in self.arrayValue {
                    let object = baseObj.init(parameter: obj)
                    arrObject.append(object!)
                }
                return arrObject
            } else {
                let object = baseObj.init(parameter: self)
                return object!
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Step 3. Use code with Alamofire or other code.

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, url).validate().responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                let json = JSON(value)

                var styles: [Style] = []
                if let styleArr = json["data"].to(type: Style.self) {
                    styles = styleArr as! [Style]
                }
                print("styles: \(styles)")
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
        }
 }
```

I hope this will be useful.

Please refer to this link for more information on this.
https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/issues/714

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function I created, feel free to use it yourself (does of course require SwiftJSON to be correctly integrated within your Xcode Swift project)...

```
func getJSON(value: [String], fileName: String) -> String{
    guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: "json"),
        let jsonData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path) else{
            print("Couldn't find the file on disk or failed to read it")
            return "ERR."
    }

    let jsonObject = JSON(data: jsonData as Data)

    guard let jsonValue = jsonObject[value].string else{
        print("FAILED to find JSON object")
        return "ERR."
    }

    return jsonValue

}
```

An example usage of this function would be `let myJsonValue = getJSON(value: ["people","person1"], fileName: "database")` which would get the value *person1* from the *people* group in the JSON file named *database.json*.  So, if the `database.json` file looked something like this

```
{
    "people" : {
        "person1" : "Bob",
        "person2" : "Steve",
        "person3" : "Alan",
    }
}
```

the function would return a value of `"Bob"`

Hope this is a help to anyone, or if you have any suggestions for it then please let me know!  Constructive criticism appreciated always.